# Strange behavior for libpq with PQconnectdb

Tags: c, postgresql-8.4

when calling PQconnectdb in the main program all run very well, but if i call it inside a function a seg fault appears.
here the code that run

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <postgresql/libpq-fe.h>



#define PG_HOST    "127.0.0.1"
#define PG_USER    "postgres"
#define PG_DB      "postgres"
#define PG_PASS    "postgres"
#define PG_PORT    5432



static void
exit_nicely(PGconn *conn)
{
    PQfinish(conn);
    exit(1);
}


int main( void )

{

char       conninfo[250];
PGconn     *conn = NULL;
PGresult   *pgres = NULL;

sprintf(conninfo, "user=%s password=%s dbname=%s hostaddr=%s port=%d", PG_USER, PG_PASS, PG_DB, PG_HOST, PG_PORT);
conn = PQconnectdb(conninfo);

if (PQstatus(conn) != CONNECTION_OK)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Connection to database failed: %s", PQerrorMessage(conn));
    exit_nicely(conn);
}


PQfinish(conn);

return 0;
}
```

this code run very well.

but when i put PQconnect inside a function, the program will generate a seg fault

```
int connect(char* conninfo, PGconn* conn)
{

conn = PQconnectdb(conninfo);

if (PQstatus(conn) != CONNECTION_OK)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Connection to database failed: %s", PQerrorMessage(conn));
    exit_nicely(conn);
}

return 1;
}




int main( void )

{

char       conninfo[250];
PGconn     *conn = NULL;
PGresult   *pgres = NULL;

sprintf(conninfo, "user=%s password=%s dbname=%s hostaddr=%s port=%d", PG_USER, PG_PASS, PG_DB, PG_HOST, PG_PORT);

connect(conninfo, conn);
if(!conn)
 fprintf(stderr, "conn is null.\n");


PQfinish(conn);

return 0;

}
```

herein the crash stack

```
(gdb) where
#0  __strlen_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strlen.S:32
#1  0x00007ffff7893086 in __GI___strdup (s=0x7 <Address 0x7 out of bounds>) at strdup.c:42
#2  0x00007ffff7bbbd87 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpq.so.5
#3  0x00007ffff7bbc2a5 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpq.so.5
#4  0x00007ffff7bbe389 in PQconnectStart () from /usr/lib/libpq.so.5
#5  0x00007ffff7bbe416 in PQconnectdb () from /usr/lib/libpq.so.5
#6  0x0000000000400912 in connect (conninfo=0x7 <Address 0x7 out of bounds>, conn=0x60a630) at pqconnect.c:25
#7  0x00007ffff7bbcadb in PQconnectPoll () from /usr/lib/libpq.so.5
#8  0x00007ffff7bbd77e in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpq.so.5
#9  0x00007ffff7bbe3b4 in PQconnectStart () from /usr/lib/libpq.so.5
#10 0x00007ffff7bbe416 in PQconnectdb () from /usr/lib/libpq.so.5
#11 0x0000000000400912 in connect (conninfo=0x7fffffffe600 "user=btel_user password=JwN5K9e18PsTb dbname=ULIC hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432", conn=0x0) at pqconnect.c:25
```

#12 0x00000000004009e3 in main () at pqconnect.c:49

When i declare my function connect as static, the seg fault error doesn't occur but the returned pointer for the variable conn is NULL

WHY? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a mixup between your `connect` and the standard library `connect`. Your `connect` takes precedence, so when `PQconnectdb` tries to call `connect`, things would go bad.
Try to rename the function.
Making `connect` static also prevents the mixup, which explains why the crash is removed.

Also, you pass the `conn` parameter to `connect` incorrectly. It's passed by value, so the variable in `main` isn't changed, and stays `NULL`.
You need to pass it by reference.

Comment: I ve rename the function, there is no SEG fault now, but when the function returns conn variable is null.???

Comment: @elhadi, see the second part of my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, i need to declare the variable conn as PGconn** conn. in this case the program run correctly

Comment: @elhadi, can you please post or send me how exactly (the final _main()_ and _connect()_ code) you solved the last problem (_when the function returns conn variable is null_), because I am in the same situation but I'm doing something wrong cause I declare the variable `PGconn** conn` and I don't get the correct effect.

Answer (score 1):

Note: @Aleix ==> This code should run well.

```
int pg_connect(char* conninfo, PGconn** conn)
{

    *conn = PQconnectdb(conninfo);
    if (PQstatus(*conn) != CONNECTION_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "ERROR: Connection to database failed: %s",
                PQerrorMessage(*conn));
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

/* set correctely your values here */
#define PG_HOST    "127.0.0.1"
#define PG_USER    "postgres"
#define PG_DB      "postgres"
#define PG_PASS    "postgres"
#define PG_PORT    5432

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char        conninfo[250];
    PGconn     *conn  = NULL;
    PGresult   *pgres = NULL;

    sprintf(conninfo,
            "user=%s password=%s dbname=%s hostaddr=%s port=%d",
            PG_USER, PG_PASS, PG_DB, PG_HOST, PG_PORT);

    if (!pg_connect(conninfo, &conn)) {
        goto end;
    }


    /*
        Here fit your staff
     */


    end:
      PQfinish(conn);
      return 0;

}
```